# Remove item from Faltlist through React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm learning React Redux at the moment and I'm working on a food list in which the user can add and remove items from a `Flatlist`, up until now I worked on adding the items, which works perfectly, now I'm using the same approach to remove the item from the global state `foodList`, I use `onLongPress` to start the function removeFromFoodList in the `Diet` screen. When I run the code and I proceed to remove the item nothing happens and no error shows. Thank you for your help.

**Diet**

```
class Diet extends Component {
  

removeItem = () => {
    let foodList = this.props.foodList;
    this.props.removeFromFoodList(foodList)
  }

 render() {

       return (

                     <FlatList
                      data={this.props.foodList}
                      renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <View>
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            onLongPress={this.removeItem}
                          >
                            <Text>{item.foodName}</Text>
                              <Text>
                                {item.calories}
                              </Text>
                              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-forward-ios" />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>
                      )}
                      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />

}
}

function mapStateToProps(store){
  return{
      foodList: store.userState.foodList
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { removeFromFoodList };


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Diet);
```

**INDEX**

```
import {  ADD_FOOD, REMOVE_FOOD } from "../constants/index";

export const updateFoodList = (foodList) => {
  return { type: ADD_FOOD, payload: foodList}
}

export const removeFromFoodList = (foodList) => {
  return { type: REMOVE_FOOD, payload: foodList}
}
```

**REDUCERS**

```
import { ADD_FOOD, REMOVE_FOOD } from "../constants";

const initialState = {
  foodList: [],
};

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case ADD_FOOD: 
      return{
        ...state,
        foodList: [...action.payload],
      }
      case REMOVE_FOOD: 
      return{
        ...state,
        foodList: [...state.foodList.filter((item) => item.id != id)],
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
  
};
```

**ARRAY EXAMPLE**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "calories": "120",
    "foodId": 0.8845240802796346,
    "foodName": "Rice",
  },
]
```

Comment: You must create an "action" function, then import it to your component and then put it to your `mapDispatchToProps` object, otherwise its undefined

Comment: Yes I am using in Diet screen, if you scroll down the page you can see it's there

Comment: I dont see import thou like `import removeFromFoodList from '../../somePath'`

Comment: I just edited the code because Visual Studio didn't update one of the pages, anyway now it recognizes the function correctly, however when I run the code nothing happens in the Flatlist, it just reloads the same list of objects

Comment: Because you pass `foodList` to an action, not a single item id like it must be, also notice than in reducer you must do `foodList: [...state.foodList.filter((item) => item.id != action.id)]`

Comment: 1. Did you import the `removeFromFoodList` from index to Diet file?
2. The INDEX file you are refering is generally called ACTIONS.
3. Here, in REDUCERS, `foodList: [...state.foodList.filter((item) => item.id != *id)],`
where is the *id coming from?

You have to send the item or item's id from Diet class on long press method (not the whole array) and filter the current foodList state in REDUCERS.
May be this will help you through it.
https://nobrok.com/the-beginners-guide-to-understanding-react-native-redux-part-1